# How to get all tables and fields together?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database and have a problem with SQL. I want to access all the tables from a database, returning the table-names and the minimum value of a known column for each table.

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM ALL_TABLES
WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'MyOwnDB'
```

and

```
SELECT min(tb.MyColumn)
FROM anyOfMyTables tb
```

Both work fine, but how could I put these queries together like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, min(tb.MyColumn)
FROM ...
```

I'm not very experienced in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single SQL statement, but you could do this with PL/SQL.

1) If all tables have a column called MYCOLUMN (unlikely):

```
declare
  l_minval date;
begin
  for r in
    ( select table_name, owner
      from  all_tables
      where ...
    )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select min(mycolumn) from '||r.owner||'.'||r.table_name 
       into l_minval;
    dbms_output.put_line(r.table_name||' '||l_minval);
  end loop;
end;
```

2) If not all tables have a column called MYCOLUMN (more likely):

```
declare
  l_minval date;
begin
  for r in
    ( select table_name, owner
      from  all_tab_columns
      where column_name = 'MYCOLUMN'
      and ...
    )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select min(mycolumn) from '||r.owner||'.'||r.table_name
       into l_minval;
    dbms_output.put_line(r.table_name||' '||l_minval);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I think you need add name of owner to table_name because the query select data from `all_tables`

Comment: the min() function should return a date,

Comment: so I change the   l_minval to DATE, but there appears a error: ora-00904 invalid identifier - with a specific table it works - and how can I get the Tables and the date together in a java-resultset? - the Java-resultset works allready with simple SQL querys

Comment: @user5497819 - check version 2 added above.

Comment: It works, but it makes the output in the console and I need it in a java resultset,

Comment: I think dbms_output.put_line() return it in a console instead of a Java resultset

Comment: Yes. I don't know about Java resultsets specifically but you could make the code into a function that returns either a collection or a ref cursor.